# Enabling a date-picker in Woocommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, datepicker, checkout

I'm trying to change checkout fields in woocomerce, from addres1 and addres2 to checkin, and checkout. I would like to use Datepiker on those two fields. This is an extract of my `WC_Countries` Class core code that I have changed:

```
            'checkin'  => array(
            'id'           =>'datepicker',
            'label'        => __( 'check in', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder'  => __( 'check in', 'woocommerce' ),
            'required'     => false,
            'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide',),
            'autocomplete' => 'datepicker',
            'priority'     => 50,
        ),
        'checkout'  => array(
            'id'           =>'datepicker',
            'placeholder'  => __( 'check out', 'woocommerce' ),
            'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide'),
            'required'     => false,
            'autocomplete' => 'datepicker',
            'priority'     => 60,
```

I have also add

```
    $('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
});
```

To my custom.scripts.js in themes directory but it doesn't work…

Is there any way to add [Datepicker](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=range&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) in to the checkout fields in woocommerce?

Comment: I don't see any `.input-daterange` anywhere

Comment: where i should add '.input-daterange' ? any tips pls :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First **NEVER override Woocommerce core files**… Is strictly discouraged and will avoid you many problems.
>
> Instead you can use all thousands of available hooks, editable templates or extend existing classes…

You can try the following code example that will add a custom checkout field with **jQuery UI datepicker** enabled for it:

```
// Register main datepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_picker' );
function enabling_date_picker() {
    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

    // Load the datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css", '', '', false);
}

// Add custom checkout datepicker field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'datepicker_custom_field' );
function datepicker_custom_field($checkout) {
    $datepicker_slug = 'my_datepicker';

    echo '<div id="datepicker-wrapper">';

    woocommerce_form_field($datepicker_slug, array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class'=> array( 'form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'label' => __('My Custom Date-picker'),
        'required' => true, // Or false
    ), '' );

    echo '<br clear="all"></div>';


    // Jquery: Enable the Datepicker
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var a = '#<?php echo $datepicker_slug ?>';
        $(a).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', // ISO formatting date
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

You will get something like:

[image]

> In the first function, you will be able to change the styling easily to match with Bootstap styles…

Comment: Many Thanks it works great :), Flowing Your advice about keeping original woocomerce files i will have too backup my commerce data :). ehh... many work ahead me to learn how to use it in proper way xD