# How to change the subtotal and total based on the calculation of pickup and delivery date on checkout?

Tags: woocommerce, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need help with a wp date picker. The thing that I want is - customers on the checkout page can choose the pickup and delivery date. After choosing the date, the in-cart summary shows the calculation - For example, if I choose from 24.07 - 26.07, then the calculation shows 2 days and multiply the price of the product x2. I'll add a screenshot of what I need.

Right now I have this (functions.php) -

```
// Add custom checkout date picker fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'datepicker_custom_fields' );
function datepicker_custom_fields( $checkout ) {
    $pickup_datepicker_slug = 'pickup_datepicker';
    $delivery_datepicker_slug = 'delivery_datepicker';
 
    echo '<div id="datepicker-wrapper">';
 
    woocommerce_form_field( $pickup_datepicker_slug, array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class'=> array( 'form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'label' => __('Pickup date'),
        'required' => true,
    ), '' );
 
    woocommerce_form_field( $delivery_datepicker_slug, array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class'=> array( 'form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'label' => __('Delivery date'),
        'required' => true,
    ), '' );
 
    echo '<br clear="all"></div>';
 
    // Jquery: Enable the Datepicker
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var pickup = '#<?php echo $pickup_datepicker_slug ?>';
        var delivery = '#<?php echo $delivery_datepicker_slug ?>';
        $(pickup).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', // ISO formatting date
        });
        $(delivery).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', // ISO formatting date
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
 
// Display additional information after order total in checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'display_additional_info_after_total' );
function display_additional_info_after_total() {
    // Get the pickup and delivery dates from the POST request (checkout page)
    $pickup_date = isset( $_POST['pickup_datepicker'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['pickup_datepicker'] ) : '';
    $delivery_date = isset( $_POST['delivery_datepicker'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_datepicker'] ) : '';
 
    // Calculate the difference in days between pickup and delivery dates
    $pickup_timestamp = strtotime( $pickup_date );
    $delivery_timestamp = strtotime( $delivery_date );
    $days_difference = ceil( ( $delivery_timestamp - $pickup_timestamp ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) );
 
    // Calculate the fee based on the cart subtotal and days difference
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    $fee = $cart->subtotal * $days_difference; // Modify this formula if needed
 
    // Display the additional information
    if ( $days_difference > 0 ) {
        echo '<p>Total ' . wc_price( $cart->subtotal + $fee ) . ' ( ' . wc_price( $fee ) . ' x ' . $days_difference . ' dienas )</p>';
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to achieve `I choose from 24.07 - 26.07, then in the calculation shows 2days and multiply the price of the product x2.` ?

Comment: tried to add two calendars then make a formula and calculate but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Ok, can you update that tried code?

Comment: Functions.php code - https://pastebin.com/sy4Vh2MP
and review-order.php code - https://pastebin.com/qc3QbpGW

Now the problem is that, the price and days count are not showing in Total. What can be the problem ?

Comment: Could you help ?

Comment: Please update the code in your question so everybody can see it.

Comment: I added a pastebin link where the code is.. But okay, updated the code in my question too.

Comment: `the calculation shows 2days and multiply the price of the product x2.` is this only show purpose or it also change the actual price through out the order process?

Comment: change the actual price through out the order process. As i said, in the checkout page needs to change the Total price if customer select atleast rent for 2 days ( product_price * 2 ). The payment method will be manually, customer just can make an order and then the administrator will process the order.

Comment: Is there will be multiple items in the cart? also, the price only changed to the total? not the product price * days?

Comment: Yeah, there can be multiple items in the cart. Yeah, can change only in the - subtotal or total.. I guess better will be in Subtotal because there is an TAX calculation too. So, if change the subtotal * days, then in Total will shows correctly total price with tax.

Comment: any ideas where the problem can be ?

Comment: I think you can't change the subtotal and total directly without the cart item price being changed. Because woocommerce calculates subtotal and total based on cart items, tax, fees, etc... even if you change subtotal and total somehow on checkout woo commerce will recalculate based on cart item price.

Comment: I don't think so.. I added a sreenshot where one store have that. I want to understand why its not show anything when i choose the dates... Is there any problems in the code or where?

Comment: There is problem with POST request, right ? The calendar selected dates not sending any information to server, im right ? What problem can be and how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about which theme you are using but you can do something like this.

On date picker `onSelect` event you can trigger `update_checkout` by this woocommerce called `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`

```
// Add custom checkout datepicker fields
function datepicker_custom_fields( $checkout ) {
    $pickup_datepicker_slug = 'pickup_datepicker';
    $delivery_datepicker_slug = 'delivery_datepicker';

    echo '<div id="datepicker-wrapper">';
 
    woocommerce_form_field( $pickup_datepicker_slug, array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class'=> array( 'form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'label' => __('Pickup date'),
        'required' => true,
    ), WC()->session->get( 'pickup_datepicker' ) );
 
    woocommerce_form_field( $delivery_datepicker_slug, array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class'=> array( 'form-row-first my-datepicker'),
        'label' => __('Delivery date'),
        'required' => true,
    ), WC()->session->get( 'delivery_datepicker' ) );
 
    echo '<br clear="all"></div>';

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            var pickup = '#pickup_datepicker';
            var delivery = '#delivery_datepicker';
            $(pickup).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', // ISO formatting date
                onSelect: function(selected) {
                    var selectedDate = selected.split('.').reverse().join('-'); // Convert to 'yy-mm-dd' format
                    var minDate = new Date(selectedDate);
                    minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                    $(delivery).datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
                    calculateDays();
                }
            });
            $(delivery).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', // ISO formatting date
                onSelect: function(selected) {
                    calculateDays();
                }
            });

            // Function to calculate the days between two dates
            function calculateDays() {
                $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
            }

        });
    </script>
    <?php

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'datepicker_custom_fields' );
```

In this filter, you can catch your `pickup_datepicker` and `delivery_datepicker` value and calculate days using the `DateTime` class and `diff` function. and set the cart item price using the `set_price` function.

```
function override_cart_item_price( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ){
        return;
    }

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ){
        return;
    }

    parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $post_data);

    if (isset($post_data['pickup_datepicker']) && $post_data['pickup_datepicker'] != '' && isset($post_data['delivery_datepicker']) && $post_data['delivery_datepicker'] != '') {

        WC()->session->set('pickup_datepicker', sanitize_text_field($post_data['pickup_datepicker']));
        WC()->session->set('delivery_datepicker', sanitize_text_field($post_data['delivery_datepicker']));

        $pickup_datepicker = sanitize_text_field($post_data['pickup_datepicker']);
        $delivery_datepicker = sanitize_text_field($post_data['delivery_datepicker']);

        $pickup_date_obj = new DateTime($pickup_datepicker);
        $delivery_date_obj = new DateTime($delivery_datepicker);

        $interval = $pickup_date_obj->diff($delivery_date_obj);
        $days = $interval->days;
        $days = ( $days > 1 ) ? $days : 1 ;
        
        WC()->session->set('delivery_days', $days );

        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            // Calculate the new subtotal and total based on the number of days
            $new_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price() * $days;
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price );    
            $cart_item['days'] = $days;
        }
    }
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'override_cart_item_price', 99, 1 );
```

By using this filter you can show a number of days beside the price.

```
function add_days_woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal( $total, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    $delivery_days = WC()->session->get( 'delivery_days' );
    if( $delivery_days ){
        $day_label = 'day';
        $product  = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
        if( $delivery_days > 1 ){
            $day_label = 'days';
        }
        $total = wc_price( $product->get_price() ) . ' x '. $delivery_days. '('.$day_label.')' . ' = '. $total;
    }
    return $total;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'add_days_woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 10, 3 );
```

References:

- [Delivery Date Option on Checkout Page -
  WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/delivery-date-option-on-checkout-page/)
- [Woocommerce checkout update totals with datepicker - WordPress Stack
  Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188976/woocommerce-checkout-update-totals-with-datepicker)
- [Custom WooCommerce datepicker checkout field saved and displayed on
  orders and emails - Stack
  Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393162/custom-woocommerce-datepicker-checkout-field-saved-and-displayed-on-orders-and-e)

Tested and working.

[image]

**UPDATE** as per OP's comment.

You can override `plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php` to your theme `yourthemename/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php`

Reference

- [How to override WooCommerce template
  files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256088/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files)

You will find this below code. and change according to your requirement.

```
<tr class="order-total">
    <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks god, it's working. But is it possible to change a little bit. Add the days in total only. Here will be an example as I think - https://prnt.sc/XYbZvrosZ7h5

Comment: Could you check the image what i added ? Maybe can make small changes or say where and what i need to change to get that result what I want / need.
And of course, Ill accept the answer, you're a god! :)

Comment: Hey,
trying to add in email customer-processing-order.php the days and total but customer email the fields is just blank. What can be the problem ?
My functions.php file - https://pastebin.com/y3jSdktq
And customer-processing-order.php file - https://pastebin.com/1WUztD8K

Could you please check and suggest what I need to do ?
https://prnt.sc/MpXwKmGVDVEg

Comment: Try to save `days` to item meta.